# How to run jest files that have no .test. in their filename?

Tags: jestjs

I have some tests that are ment to be run aside from all other `.test` files so I called them `.integration.js`

how to test all files that have `.integration.js`?

example file;
`endpoint.integration.js`

Comment: You can configure custom test file names. https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testregex-string

Comment: write this and I will accept is as an answer. I was looking for this all along

Comment: I've submitted an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can configure custom test file names with the config key `testRegex`.
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testregex-string--arraystring

The default is: `(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.[jt]sx?$`

So to only run tests in files like `endpoint.integration.js` tests, you can use this regex instead: `\\.integration\\.js$`

You can put this in your configuration either in `package.json` or `jest.config.js`.

Or you can use the regex as the first argument to the jest cli command.

```
jest '\\.integration\\.js$'
```

Comment: Haven't tried the configuration method, but the cli argument does not work as above, as of jest 29.7.0.
The regex argument is applied only as an additional filter to the set of files that have already passed the configured pattern.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// jest.config.ts

const config: Config = {
    testRegex: ['\\.spec\\.[jt]sx?$'], // match file.spec.ts, file.spec.jsx...
    ...
}
```

- the regexp shall be type string and not a real Regexp
- dots and other regexp special character shall be escaped as well as escape character in the string, that's why we need double escape (eg. `\\.`)
- See [documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testregex-string--arraystring)